# Java - Huge object size Serialization taking longer time Memcached

Tags: java, serialization, garbage-collection, deserialization, memcached

We are trying to insert very large objects approx 350 MB into Memcached, these objects are basically beans that have evolved over the time and have multiple properties(Bean) which are carrying key data that can not be compromised with. Due to the large size of the object, serialization is taking ample amount of time and causing the system to respond very slow in case of multiple concurrent users.

I have tried a combination of Folsom@Spotify java memcached client + Kryo(Serialization) + Snappy-java(Compression). After serialization & compression, object size become around 30 MB. Which is still a very large object to store in Memcached.

There are two main java beans which has multiple properties(getters and setters) but not all the properties from these beans are required to be stored in Memcached. 
Please suggest any alternate approach available for handling huge objects while working with Memcache.

Comment: Am I getting it correctly? You deserialize a huge object, modify it and serialize it again, for every user request?

Comment: User performed a search on our application, we fetch inventories from multiple suppliers system using XML-web services. Each supplier XML parsed, data captured and set in Beans(List<Bean>) then inventories from different suppliers merged into final list, this final list got set in a parent Bean and this bean is being stored in Memcached.
Inventories object (created after supplier XML parsing) -> Serialized -> Compressed -> then stored in Memcache. deserialization is not done at this stage.

Comment: What’s the purpose of serializing something when it never gets deserialized? Besides, the problem seems to be at the “*this final list got set in a parent Bean*”, as when not constructing a humongous contains-all bean, you don’t have the problem connected with serializing very large objects.

Comment: During Search operation, data captured from all suppliers(XML-services) and get merged in a final list then it get stored in Memcache against an unique search number for later use. When user select one inventory and proceed to confirm it then these cached inventories data fetched from Memcache(including selected inventory data) and then selected inventory data being used in flow for confirmation process. Here, serialization required before storing it in Memcached and DeSerialization required when we fetch inventories from Memcached to use it in next step.

Comment: Reflection is slow in general. I suspect Kryo uses reflection in an optimized way to provide default serialization implementations, in which case (de)serialization would be faster if you instead implemented it yourself via the Externalizable interface. This simply avoids reflection by handing over the object streams to you as the programmer to be read from/written to.